# id attribute not updating in sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to update an sqlite table row(id, data columns) from rails console. All the models attributes are updating but when updating the id attribute of the model, nothing happens.

```
irb(main):023:0> r = Person.find(4)
=> #<Person id: 4, data: "threeplusone">
irb(main):024:0> r.update_attributes({:id=>5})
=> true
irb(main):025:0> r.save
=> true
```

Above prints true but when i inspect the sqlite db id is not updated to 5.

```
irb(main):026:0> r = Person.find(4)
=> #<Person id: 4, data: "threeplusone">
irb(main):027:0> r.update_attributes({:data=>'TRIplusone'})
=> true
irb(main):028:0> r.save
=> true
```

Above prints true and the data attribute is updating well.

And my model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base 
 attr_accessor :id,:data
 attr_accessible :id,:data
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails won't let you update the `id` attribute easily. You could execute the following SQL though, and it should work. (Also, when you use the `update_attributes(...)` method, you don't need to call `.save` afterward).

```
sql = "update people set id=5 where id=4"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Thanks Dylan it works. I tried like this  `r.connection.execute("update people set id=5 where id=4")`